# TypeError while converting int to string in python

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm using `str()` to convert int to string but I am getting `TypeError`.

This is the code which I have written:

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
    name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
    name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
    i=0
    a=0
    b=0
    c=0
    d=0
    str="TRUE"
    str1="LOVE"
    while i<4:
      a+=name1.count(str[i])
      b+=name2.count(str[i])
      c+=name1.count(str1[i])
      d+=name2.count(str1[i])
      i+=1
    a=a+b
    c=c+d
    print("Your score is",str(a)+str(b))
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    a=str(a)
Type error: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please update your question with the text of your code.

Comment: Edit you code with full traceback error and the code, Don't post a screenshot.

Comment: `str="TRUE"` - error is here. Do not use name of built-in types/classes as name of variables.

Comment: replace the code screenshot to the code

Comment: You defined a `str` variable. Don't redefine built-ins.

Comment: Your error traceback does not correspond to the code you have posted. Please check both and post your real code.

Answer (score 3):

you defined `str` as a string, That's why python thinks `str` is a string, not a function that is why it's throwing `TypeError`.

Renaming the `str` variable to something else will solve the work

**solution**

```py
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
i = a = b = c = d = 0
str1 = "TRUE"
str2 = "LOVE"
while i < 4:
    a += name1.count(str1[i])
    b += name2.count(str1[i])
    c += name1.count(str2[i])
    d += name2.count(str2[i])
    i += 1
a += b
c += d

print("Your score is", str(a)+str(b))
```

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this error, you need to change the name of the variable whose name is similar to the in-built function str() used in the code.

Instead, try this:

```
print("Your score is",str(str(a)+str(b)))
```

Comment: your example code has nothing to do with the sentence. There's no need for the redundant cast to str: the product of a string concatenation is already a str.